# Visual Studio Express - Simple build configuration error

Tags: visual-studio, build

I've switched to a new computer but copied all my project files to it. I am getting this error when I try to run:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(806,5): error MSB3191: Unable to create directory "C:\Users\MyUser\StarFall\StarFall_build\CMakeFiles\". Access to the path 'C:\Users\MyUser\StarFall\StarFall_build\CMakeFiles\' is denied.
```

The path has changed, but I don't know where I can change this setting. I realise that this may be specific to what my project settings are, but if you need more details I will post them!

Answer (score 3):

Like Arun mentioned, this kind of an error happens when there is a macro in your project which is pointing to a wrong location. You shouldn't change the microsoft.cppbuild.targets file. Instead, go to your project properties and change the directory paths that are erroneous.
You can see macro expansions when you click on the dropdown arrow beside a macro, click edit and click Macros>>

Answer (score 1):

From your message, I guess, it is defined in file:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets
```

at line 806,column 5

Comment: +1 for trolls, but I had a message like that before and it was somewhere in the properties.

Comment: The line in that file is: `<MakeDir Directories="@(ClDirsToMake)" />` I still don't know how to change that property

Comment: I would personally not change anything in that file. I believe somewhere in your settings, you have the "SourceFilePath" (or something like that) set incorrectly, perhaps due to the way how location was set in your old machine.

Comment: I knew that the path was incorrect, but I don't know whereabouts in the project setting the place is to change it =/ I'll see if I can find sourcefilepath or something

Comment: Some Macro is still pointing to your old location. Under Project Menu, try opening Properties. Switch to "Configuration Properties". Under one of those values on your right (let us take "Output Directory"), click on the tiny drop down, choose "Edit". You should see a "Macros" button, click on it. Check if any path that you see in the list is still pointing to your old location (possible culprit is "InputDir" row).

Comment: I've found two, thanks. But what do I do, now that I've found them...?

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: @PigHead let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2971/discussion-between-arun-and-pig-head)